# Arduino processing open network sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking, arduino

Is there a way via Arduino Processing (The program running on the computer) to open a network socket? I would like to open a client or server socket on the processing program so i can talk to it via WiFi and control my Arduino over serial connection. The serial connection stuff is working, all i want now is some way to control the processing over a network. Sure i could directly control the Arduino with a wifi shield, but don't worry about that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question your looking to do networking in Processing.  There is a [library](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/index.html) to do exactly that.  It allows you to create simple clients or servers.

`The Network library makes it easy to read and write data across machines on the  Internet. It allows the creation clients and servers. A server connects to a list of clients for reading and writing data. A client is able to read and write data to a server.`

Best of luck.

Comment: does this require the ethernet shield? It seems to assume TCP/IP but there is no mention of the transport layer

Comment: Processing is a companion project that runs on a PC. Processing is designed to interface with an arduino. It uses the PC's resources including networking.
From the [arduino website](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Processing):

`Processing is an open source language/ development tool for writing programs in other computers. Useful when you want those other computers to "talk" with an Arduino, for instance to display or save some data collected by the Arduino.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a [library](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/SerialIP) to do [SLIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIP) (serial line internet protocol) with an Arduino without an ethernet card

Comment: Okay, exactly HOW do i go about using a "library"?